# How to read CSV header in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting.I need shell script which read csv headers and footer.
Thanks

Comment: `head -1` and `tail -1`

Answer (score 0):

to be quick, 2 basic tool for text file manipulation: sed and awk
you can also use grep is few or no modification but just catching info

with sed:

```
# print 1st and last line only (-n mean no print by default, p mean print)
sed -n '1p;$p' YourFile
#or
# print if 1st, print if last, delete line (no print)
sed -e '1p;$p;d' YourFile
```

with awk:

```
 # print first, remind last line read, at the end print last know line
 awk '1;{last=$0};END{print $0)' YourFile

 # but you can work on content like
 awk '1{for(f=1;f<=NF;f++)h[i]=$1};{last=$0};END{split($0,a);for( j in h) printf( "%d:%s -> %s\n", j, h[j], a[j])}' YourFile
```

it depend on what you want to do (next)